# Python-Beautiful Soup How to get tags and texts from a xml file even not knowing all the names of the tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a xml file like this:

```
 <a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
  <d>
    <e>3</e>
  </d>
</a>
<a>
  <c>4</c>
  <f value ="something">5</f>
  <g value = "other"></g>
</a>
```

and I want a list of dicts with the tags and the text.
E.g:

```
[{'b':1, 'c':2, 'e':3}, {'c':4, 'f value="something"':5, 'g value = "other"':None}]
```

It's a big xml file and it's not standard, so I only know that `<a>` exists and I want all the info inside this tag.

I already tried Beautiful Soup 4, but I could only retrieve the text parts.

My code

```
def ProcessXml(xmlFile):
    infile = open(xmlFile, 'r')
    contents = infile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
    units = soup.find_all('a')
    unitsList = []
    for i in units:
        resultType = i.text,i.next_sibling
        resultType = resultType[0].splitlines()
        for j in resultType:
            if j == '':
                resultType.remove(j)
        unitsList.append((resultType))

    return unitsList
```

My output:

```
[['1','2','3'],['4','5']]
```

Comment: This is possible in bs4. What part of it didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm new in bs4 and python and i only could figure out this:                     units = soup.find_all('a')                                                                           for i in units: resultType = i.text,i.next_sibling  Thank you @TankorSmash

Comment: Can you edit that into your question? That'll help others answer your question. Hard to read unformatted code.

Comment: Done! Thank you @TankorSmash

Comment: Have you tried [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)?

Comment: `'g value = "other"'}]` This part is invalid, You have to have a value with a key be it None or 0 or empty string.

Comment: You are right @MYGz sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really bad code but does the job:

```
def len_descendant(desc):
    counter = 0
    try:
        for i in desc.descendants:
            if i!='' and i !='\n':
                counter += 1
    except Exception:
        pass
    return counter 

def ProcessXml():  
    infile = open("xmlfile.xml", 'r')
    contents = infile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')
    units = soup.find_all('a')
    unitsList = []
    for i in units:
        this_dict = {}
        for desc in i.descendants:
            print desc, len_descendant(desc)

            try:
                if desc.has_attr('value'):
                    has_attribute = True
            except Exception:
                has_attribute = False

            if len_descendant(desc)==1 or has_attribute:
                if desc.has_attr('value'):
                    key = desc.name + " " + desc.attrs.keys()[0] + '=\"' + desc.attrs.values()[0] + '\"'
                else:
                    key = desc.name

                try:
                    value = int(desc.text)
                except Exception:
                    value = None
                this_dict[key] = value
        unitsList.append(this_dict)

    return unitsList

my_dict = ProcessXml()
```

The result is:

```
[{'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 3}, {'f value="something"': 5, 'c': 4, 'g value="other"': 1}]
```

NOTE: As MYGz mentioned, `'g value = "other"'}]` part was invalid so I this is the XML file I tried the function on:

```
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <c>2</c>
  <d>
    <e>3</e>
  </d>
</a>
<a>
  <c>4</c>
  <f value ="something">5</f>
  <g value = "other">1</g>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stergios One more thing, i really need <g value = "other"></g> to return something like {'g vale = "other": None} but i can't figure out

Comment: OK I've updated the code above. It's the worst code ever but does the job :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! We post a code at the same time, but your code looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def len_descendant(desc):
    counter = 0
    try:
        for i in desc.descendants:
            #print (i)
            if i!='' and i !='\n':
                counter += 1
    except Exception:
        pass
    return counter 

def ProcessXmlTwo(fileName):  
    infile = open(fileName, 'r')
    contents = infile.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
    units = soup.find_all('a')
    #print (units)
    unitsList = []
    for i in units:
        this_dict = {}
        for desc in i.descendants:
            flagNoKey = False
            if len_descendant(desc)==1 or 'value="true"/>' in str(desc) or 'value="false"/>' in str(desc):
                if desc.has_attr('value'):
                    #print (desc.name)
                    key = desc.name + " " + list(desc.attrs.keys())[0] + '=\"' + list(desc.attrs.values())[0] + '\"'
                elif 'value="true"/>' in str(desc) or 'value="false"/>' in str(desc):
                    flagNoKey = True
                    key = desc.name + " " + list(desc.attrs.keys())[0] + '=\"' + list(desc.attrs.values())[0] + '\"'
                else:
                    key = desc.name
                if flagNoKey == False:
                    this_dict[key] = desc.text
                else:
                    this_dict[key] = "None"

        unitsList.append(this_dict)

    return unitsList
```

This is the code that i will use. This is a adaptation of of the code written by @Stergios. (works in python 3)